# Getting filenotfoundexception error since my application is looking for application.properties in gradle home instead of project directory

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

When i run a java application with gradle task using a gradle wrapper, it wasn’t able to load the app.property file, when i checked the path of the file it’s not looking good.

I'm seeing it as /Users/user/.gradle/daemon/6.3/src/main/resources/application.properties219 ideally it should be /Users/user/Project/src/main/resources/application.properties

How to fix this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the problem you are having? Like the Bot suggested above, sharing some code may help.